# Alterar visibilidade de uma DIV baseado na valor de dois select usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho 2 select options. Se a opção do select1 AND a opção do select2 forem selecionadas, não aparece nada. Caso contrário aparece um formulário.

HTML

```
   <div class="form-group" style="color:black">
      <select id="test1" name="test1">
          <option value=""> Seleciona</option>
           <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
           <option value="Não"> Não </option>
        </select>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group" style="color:black">
          <label> Com Consequentimento? </label >
         <select id="conse" name="consente_vq" >
           <option value=""> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
        <form> //aqui teria perguntas </form>
     </div>
```

Eu queria que quando "test1" == 'Não' && "test2" == 'Não' o "form2" NÃO aparece, caso contrário já aparece.

Eu consegui apenas com um select. Algo assim:

Javascript

```
    <script> $("#test1").change(function(){
       if($(this).val() == 'Não'){
           $("#form2").hide();
       }else{
           $("#form2").show();
       }

       });
    </script>
```

Mas quando tento fazer com os 2 select já não consigo

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/val/), a função ***val***:

> Obtém o valor atual do primeiro elemento no conjunto de elementos
> correspondidos ou defina o valor de cada elemento correspondido.

Assim, fiz algumas edições no seu código e ele ficou assim:

**Código HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group" style="color:black">
      <select id="test1" name="test1">
          <option value=""> Seleciona</option>
           <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
           <option value="Não"> Não </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="color:black">
      <label> Com Consequentimento? </label >
     <select id="conse" name="consente_vq" >
       <option value=""> Selecione </option>
        <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
        <option value="Não"> Não </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
       <form>
         <p>
           Isso deve sumir ou aparecer conforme a seleção.
         </p>
       </form>
    </div>
```

**Código JavaScript + jQuery**

```
   $("#test1").change(function(){
       verificaOps();
   });
   $("#conse").change(function(){
       verificaOps();
   });
   
   function verificaOps()
   {
    if($( "select#test1" ).val() === 'Não' &&  $( "select#conse" ).val() === 'Não'){
           $("#form2").hide();
       }else{
           $("#form2").show();
       }
   }
```

Você pode testar o código [aqui no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0vh3u8t/).

Basicamente o que nós temos dessa forma é que ao serem alterados, o evento *change* dos selects chama a função ***verificaOps***, que altera a visibilidade da div do form caso a opção não tenha sido selecionada em ambos.